# Android - Stop MediaPlayer from downloading more content but continue playing buffered content

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a MediaPlayer that plays content from a URL, MP3s that can be up to an hour long. Obviously as  it's playing, MediaPlayer buffers content further into the MP3. What I'd like to be able to do is stop MediaPlayer at certain points and allow it to continue playing back the content it has already buffered.  Is that possible? I can't find anything in the docs to make it seem like it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play partially downloaded files (at least it works with video files). Download till you reach the desired file length and start playing the local file.